# How to scrape data in selenium without being detected as a robot in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium and am very confused why this is not working. I am trying to login to their page first because it requires an account to view their articles. I think I've done that part. However, now, when I try to view the article it tells me that I can't view it because it's a robot.

the current code I have is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = './chromedriver'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

LOGIN_PAGE = "https://www.seekingalpha.com/login"
ACCOUNT = "ACCOUNT"
PASSWORD = "PASSWORD"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.seekingalpha.com/login")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "email"))).send_keys(ACCOUNT)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "signInPasswordField"))).send_keys(PASSWORD)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Sign in']"))).click()

driver.get("https://seekingalpha.com/article/4414043-agenus-inc-agen-ceo-garo-armen-on-q4-2020-results-earnings-call-transcript")
text_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*')

text = text_element

for t in text:
    print(t.text)
```

and I get

```
Is this happening to you frequently? Please report it on our feedback forum.
If you have an ad-blocker enabled you may be blocked from proceeding. Please disable your ad-blocker and refresh.
Reference ID: cbbe4cb0-b4c7-11eb-87a2-97a8b0029776
To continue, please prove you are not a robot
...
```

Comment: I am not sure it is legal. If you have a legit reason to use selenium on that site, check with the website admin.

Comment: There can be many reasons why you keep getting flagged as a robot. I cannot give you an absolute answer as every website can have its own techniques implemented. Scrapping can be a matter of try/errors investigations. However some hints about what may go wrong : you execute your script from a server which is known to belong to a datacenter or whatever, your IP has previously been flagged while your were starting to implement your algorithm (and still blacklists it), the way you navigate the website (delays, mouse movements, etc...) are not representative of a human, etc...